# wicked_pdf render thai text incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I want to render thai text with `wicked_pdf` which uses `wkhtmltopdf`, but the resulting PDF is incorrect as you can see below. I try setting the font with css `font-family` but it doesn't help. My template has `<meta charset='utf-8' />`

Incorrect:
[image]
Correct:
[image]

**Update:**
I tried to convert a html with thai text to pdf using the `wkhtmltopdf` cli and the text is rendered correctly. I tried to point `wicked_pdf` to the same executable, but the problem still occur when rendered in `wicked_pdf`

Answer (score 1):

When you render the pdf, try passing "UTF-8" to the encoding option as well.

```
render pdf: "my_pdf", encoding: "UTF-8"
```

Comment: @harinsa did you find a solution ?

Comment: @MarieDianaTran Sadly no, I went with another solution instead, namely using generating pdf through jasperstarter